# Link to S3 file with Data URI

Tags: html, image, amazon-s3

- I have file in S3 which contain data URI of the image
- File is publicly visible
- I tried to use link to that file in my img html tag

  img src="https://link_to_s3/file_with_data_uri"

but unfortunately browser do not recognize that the data is actually data uri

how can I do it?

Comment: Are you saying the image is stored as base64 ("data URI")?  What is the `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding` headers of the file set to, in S3 (these are visible in the S3 console or in the response headers)?

Comment: Content-Type - binary/octet-stream, Content-Encoding is not set

Comment: What happens if you try setting `Content-Type: image/png` (or image/jpeg, as appropriate, note that "jpeg" has an "e" in it, even if the file is .jpg) and `Content-Encoding: base64`...?  You can edit these in the console.

Comment: tried both image/png and image/jpeg but without any success